# inversion of fields with an arabic text and a numeric variables

Tags: python, string, numeric, arabic

I need to print the below string of two fields which is first an Arabic and he second a numéric values.

```
>>> s1 = 'مرحبا بالجميع'
>>> s2 = '1'
>>> print('{} - {}'.format(s1,s2))
مرحبا بالجميع - 1
```

But the result is the numeric value and next of the arabic value.

I need to put the numeric value on right of the arabic value.

Is there a way to manage this problem

Thanks in advance

Comment: print('{} - {}'.format(s2,s1))?

Comment: Reverse the two fields works. But now I'll have to detect if my s1 field is in English or Arabic. I have both in my file.

Comment: you can check it with isascii "trial123".isascii() returns true

Answer (score 0):

If you want more control on how you map your variables within your string:

- You can use f strings
- You can specify the mapping in the `format` function

```py
# fstring
f"{s1} - {s2}"

# format with mapping
"{t1} - {t2}".format(t1=s1, t2=s2)
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it doesn't succed : the nuneric field is always on left.

Comment: Even if you swap the variables around?

Answer (score 0):

A partially solution is to frame the arabic field with brackets.

`>>> print('[{}] - {}'.format(s1,s2))`

`[مرحبا بالجميع] - 1`